# Proc report vs proc print in SAS

Tags: sas

What can we do with proc report that we cannot do with proc print?
They seem very similar in usage. It seems that they are both used to create a list style report

Comment: I don't think proc print supports across variables. Also, you can put totals/subtotals in different locations - such as above actual listing.

Comment: This isn't really a Stack Overflow question.  If you have something particular you're looking at doing in one vs. the other, then that's fine, but this question isn't.

Comment: There's a handful of whitepapers out there such as www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/170-2008.pdf , http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/141-2010.pdf , and http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2013/PO-04.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC Report is a more advanced feature as compared to PROC PRINT , which gives a listing kind of report. I don't say that print procedure is bad, as we used to use it before in a different fashion. The additional features of PROC REPORT stand out against PRINT procedure,

1. Ability to compute a variable and display it in the final report on the fly - using COMPUTE block
2. No pre-sorting required, you can do that using define <> /
3. Ability to add free style text and proper breaks for TOTALS - you can control this properly in report where as you have less control in PROC PRINT.

There are many others, but the above few I found a lot useful and differentiating as per me, others can add more though.